# Determine the $\dim_F(Span(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5))$ for $F=\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q}$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, field-theory

Hi i'm having trouble with this homework question:

> We view $\mathbb{C}^2=\{(w,z) : w,z\in \mathbb{C} \}$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q}$ (complex numbers, real numbers and rational numbers) let $$x_1=(i,0), x_2=(\sqrt2, \sqrt5), x_3=(0,1), x_4=(i \sqrt3,\sqrt3), x_5=(1,3)\in \mathbb{C}^2.$$ Determine the $\dim_F(Span(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5))$ for $F=\mathbb{C},\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q}$.

So what I've done so far is Gaussian elimination on the matrix of whom columns are $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5$. From this I think that the number of basis vectors would be 2 so the dimension is 2. Does this mean it would be 2 for all of them as I have always taken the number of basis vectors to equal the dimension. I think that this is wrong though.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct over $\mathbb C$, as the scalars are complex and you must have used complex scalars to row-reduce.

But first, how were you told to express $(i, 0)$ as a vector over $\mathbb R$? One needs two real coordinates to express a complex number $z = a+bi$, where $z\in\mathbb C$ and $a, b\in\mathbb R$; so over $\mathbb R$ the way I would write it, your vector $x_1$ becomes $(0, 1, 0, 0)$, $x_2 = (\sqrt 2, 0, \sqrt 2, 0)$, and so on.  $\mathbb C^2$ is 4-dimensional over the reals, so do your Gaussian elimination again, but this time, only using real scalars.

The next thing you have to consider is that real *numbers* may be independent of each other over $\mathbb Q$, so even more vectors may be linearly independent if the only scalars allowed are rational. I would write the vectors in the same way as over $\mathbb R$.  But for example, is there any *rational* scalar $c$ for which $\sqrt 2 = c * 3$?  Use this to determine if $x_5$ is in the span of $x_2$, and so on.  (I.e. do Gaussian elimination again, but now with only rational scalars.)

As this is a homework problem I'll leave it there, but I hope this gives you a path forward.

Comment: Yes this does help a lot thank you